# Microsoft Outlook: How to add a shortcut for good looking quoting? (So that it is also permanently available.)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, styles

Outlook doesn't have a "Quote" button, which was a standard thing back in the days. I mean a quick shortcut to add "Quote" style to snippets of text. Like Gmail does with a vertical line and a small indentation. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by manually adding a Style for this. However, Microsoft has neglected this, therefore this is convoluted. With workarounds it is still possible to get this working.

- New email. Write something in the email text for testing purposes. Then click the tab Format Text to create your desired style. In this case we create a style called “Quote (vertical line)”.
- Increase Indent (click on the button with an arrow to the right).
- Click on the Border button’s arrow down, Borders and Shading. Color some dark blue. Width 3 pt. Click on the left border button (click several times if it does not update).
- Click Styles. Create a Style. Name: Quote (vertical line). OK
- Click Change Styles. Set as Default, Yes. [This is basically “SAVE STYLE SET”.]
- New email. Now you should be able to click Styles and choose your new style. The fastest way to clear the style (so that not all your email is using the style): ctrl+space.
- Note that the Style Set has to be configured on each computer, it’s not shared across computers. Also note that once you create new styles like this, deleting them doesn’t work. Deleted styles appear again when you create new email and see your Styles. Workaround for deleting unnecessary styles: Shift+Ctrl+Alt+s to open the Styles list. Click on Manage Styles at the bottom. Import/Export. In the right box, selected unwanted styles, Delete, Close.
- Add your new style to the Styles: in the Styles list (Shift+Ctrl+Alt+s) click the down arrow next to "Quote (vertical line)", Add to Style Gallery. (And you can customize the position of your style here: Styles list / Manage Styles / tab Recommend / Move Up or Down for the Style, OK.) Then again do the Changes Styles / Set as Default to "Save".

Shortcut for applying your custom style (when typing your email): alt+o l {Right} {Enter}

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. It's very useful. By the way, if you still would like this feature in Outlook, you can also create a thread in Outlook User voice, then other users will could vote on it for you, Microsoft may notice it and add it in the later version.